# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) when calling into iOS 3rd Party SDK from react-native Bridge

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I have built a small test application to test out the bridge to the 3rd party SDK. I am able to call into my iOS bridge from JS and return data to the JS app. However, as soon as I invoke a method into the iOS native 3rd party SDK, I get a "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" exception. I have a feeling that this is due to a simple configuration issue but have not had much luck searching the webs.

is this something that is common? is there anything i need to do to be able to access a native SDK from within my bridge?

Important to note: the 3rd party iOS SDK is linked to the project via CocoaPods.

Answer (score 0):

the 3rd party library was a dynamically built framework, and it seems that react-native currently does not support bridging to a dynamically built framework